# Different ColorMaps for plotyy() values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a bar plot with 2 Y-axes generated with `plotyy()` and want to assign a colormap to each of them. I tired to use `colormap(axis,map)` but it seems to overwrite the settings of the whole plot, instead of the ones from `axis` only.

My aproach:

```
[haxes,hbar1,hbar2]=plotyy(1:2,randi(2000,2,3),3:5,randi(100,3,3),'bar','bar');

set(haxes(1), 'xtickLabel', name(1:2));
set(haxes(2), 'xtickLabel', name(3:5) );
set(haxes,{'ycolor'},{'r';[67,186,52]./256});

%set(hbar1, 'facecolor', ['r','w','y']); %<- Things like this work, but are not what Iwant
colormap(haxes(1),hot)
colormap(haxes(2),summer)
```

results in this plot

[image: Resulting plot]

and I want something like this (which I generated by hand, coloring single bars)

[image: Desired object]

How can I apply two different colormaps in a single figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all the colormaps you want to use into a single colormap, then set each barseries object to index directly into the relevant bin of this colormap. E.g.

```
[haxes,hbar1,hbar2]=plotyy(1:2,randi(2000,2,3),3:5,randi(100,3,3),'bar','bar');
colormap(haxes(1),[hot(3); summer(3)])
for a = 1:3
    set(get(hbar1(a), 'Children'), 'CData', [a; a], 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
    set(get(hbar2(a), 'Children'), 'CData', [a; a; a]+3, 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
end
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does exacly what you want,

```
y = [4.2; 4.6; 5];
h = figure;

a = axes('parent', h);

hold(a, 'on')

colors = {'r', 'b', 'g'};

for i = 1:numel(y)
    bar(i, y(i), 'parent', a, 'facecolor', colors{i});
end
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sammuel, I can indeed generate bars in different colors, but can not combine them with sets of other bars generated in plots with double Y-axes. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

A colormap applies to the entire figure, and not just an axes, so when you set the colormap the second time you are just overwriting the first colormap. To quote the colormap documentation (with my own emphasis):

> `colormap(ax,...)` uses the *figure* corresponding to axes ax instead of
>   the current figure.

Comment: Thank you for your observation. I indeed thought colormap aplied to the single axes. But remember, as constructive and accurate as your comment is, it is still not an answer.

Comment: My 'observation' is an answer to _a_ question. You actually didn't ask a question, so I was inferring one, and my answer is the right one for that question. Remember, if you want an answer to a specific question then be sure to actually ask the question.

Comment: you are right, so my question was not "why is this not working", but rather "how can I make it work?". Any ideas on the second one?